# Exclude Specific Areas from Crawler

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I wanted to exclude some specific Areas from being crawled by google etc. because this is the legal/privacy and will get penalty because of long unrelated text. So I found a solution with [iframe](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/preventing-robots-from-crawling-specific-part-of-a-page). I think the best way is to create a specific route for my desired element with `htmlRoute` or `renderRoute` and `Disallow: /ROUTE/` in robots.txt. Or is there any other recommended way to solve this ? Maybe even more elegant ?

Here is my example of that code I tried `<!--googleoff: index-->` but unfortunately this isn't working anymore:

```
<footer class="page-footer">
  <div class="footer-copyright">
    <div class="footer-container">

      {%- if data.global.legal -%}
        © {{ data.global.creation_date }} {{ data.global.copyright }}
      {%- endif -%}

      {%- if data.global.privacy -%}
        <a class="grey-text text-lighten-4 right modal-trigger" href="#modal-1">privacy</a>
        <div id="modal-1" class="modal">
          <div class="modal-content text-darken-4">

            <!--googleoff: index-->

            <h4>Privacy</h4>
            {{ apos.area(data.global, 'privacy', {
              edit: false,
              widgets: { 'apostrophe-rich-text': { } }
            }) }}

            <!--googleon: index-->

          </div>
        </div>
      {%- endif -%}

      {%- if data.global.legal -%}
        <a class="grey-text text-lighten-4 right modal-trigger" href="#modal-2">Legal</a>
        <div id="modal-2" class="modal">
          <div class="modal-content text-darken-4">

            <!--googleoff: index-->

            <h4>Legal Info</h4>
            {{ apos.area(data.global, 'legal', {
              edit: false,
              widgets: { 'apostrophe-rich-text': { } }
            }) }}

            <!--googleon: index-->

          </div>
        </div>
      {%- endif -%}

    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

I've picked some example `renderRoute` function from apostrophe core modules and implemented this to my apostrophe global now my apostrophe global looks like that:

```
...
{
  name: 'legal',
  label: 'Legal Info',
  help: 'Your adress, phone and other info here',
  type: 'area',
  options: {
    widgets: {
      'apostrophe-rich-text': {
        toolbar: [
          'Styles',
          'Bold',
          'Italic',
          'Blockquote',
          'BulletedList',
          'Link'
        ],
        controls: {
          movable: false,
          cloneable: false,
          removable: true,
          position: 'top-right'
        }
       }
     }
   }
},
construct: function(self, options) {
  self.renderRoute('post', 'iframe', function(req, res, next) {
    return next(null, {
      template: 'legal'
    });
  });
}
```

But i still don't get an route like iframe when i open the legal modal. I think I made something wrong or didn't understood this function fully. I would be really thankful if you could clarify this. Maybe it's just a quick look for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`googleoff` is not for the public google crawler. It is strictly for google's old "search appliance" which was for intranet use and has been discontinued.

Your iframe tactic can work. The simplest way to get there would be to put the content in the global preferences by adding an area to the schema of `apostrophe-global`, like this:

```
// in lib/modules/apostrophe-global/index.js

module.exports = {
  addFields: [
    {
      name: 'legal',
      type: 'singleton',
      widgetType: 'apostrophe-rich-text',
      options: {
        toolbar: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Link' ]
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Then you can use `renderRoute` as you suggested, and render a template that outputs that area from the global doc.

Comment: I've updated my question above to clarify where I am stuck. Basicly I need some help to implement this `renderRoute` function.

Comment: Nothing in your code references the route you just created, which is /modules/your-module-name/iframe by the way. You don't have any iframes. Also you need to make it a "get" route if you want to use it as the src of an iframe.

Comment: I have now understood these mechanic and I think I can solve even better what I wanted. But anyway this will give me huge advantage when creating new modules. Thx for explaining me...